# How to set IMG attributes after .src change?

Tags: javascript

I'm JS newbie with some problems. I made simple script for toggle between images onClick and there is one problem. My img is child having height and width with percentage of parent's div, but after changing src of photo everything ruins and the swapped photo doesn't have any rules. Static width and height. Here my JS code:

```
    let img = document.getElementById("img");
let imgsrc = document.getElementById("img").src;
if (imgsrc.indexOf('image1.jpg')!=-1)
{
    document.getElementById('img').src = 'Photos/image1_swap.png';
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('img').src = 'Photos/image1.jpg';
}
```

Comment: You can update the `height` and `width` attributes as necessary in the same function; what part(s) are you stuck on? Also you're not really showing enough of your (relevant) code for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @DavidThomas Hey, thank you for answer. Yeah, I forgot that I have possibility to do that with .style.